# Most succinct way to enumerate the zero crossings of a particular spiral

Tags: algorithm, abstract, pseudocode

What is the most succinct way (in pseudocode) to create the following map f from the naturals to the integers
f(0) = 0;
f(1) = 1;
f(2) = -1; 
f(3) = 2;
f(4) = -2;
f(5) = 3;
etc

You can imagine them as the zero crossing of a double symmetric Archimedean spiral.

Oh, and no float math allowed! Float math would be... ugly in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+2%2C+-2%2C+3) found a closed form for calculating the n<sup>th</sup> term directly:

[image: closed form]

The expression -1<sup>n</sup> can also be written as `(n % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1)` if n is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but an one-liner that works and doesn't use conditionals:

```
f(i):
  f := (2 * (i mod 2) - 1) * ((i + 1) >> 1)
```

Of course, using conditionals, it gets more readable:

```
f(i):
  if (i mod 2) is
    0: f := -((i + 1) >> 1)
    1: f :=  ((i + 1) >> 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With C-notation, `f(n)` will be `n % 2 == 0 ? -n/2 : (n+1)/2`, i.e.:

If `n` is even then `-n/2`, if `n` is odd then `(n+1)/2`